# PHP str_replace not working when encounter apostrophe

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I want to do a str_replace on a string.
The string is "Qualité de l'air" and the modified string should be "Qualitdelair".

My code is:

```
$string = "Qualité de l'air";
$newString = str_replace(array("é", " ", "'"), "", $string);
```

I also tried:

```
$string = "Qualité de l'air";
$newString = str_replace(array("é", " ", "\'"), "", $string);
```

and:

```
$string = "Qualité de l'air";
$newString = str_replace(array("é", " ", "&#039;"), "", $string);
```

I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: What should the modified string be?

Comment: $newString should be "Qualitdelair"

Comment: [Your code works](https://ideone.com/LdbVWm). Did you use `htmlentities()` somewhere above that code? Try `$newString = str_replace(array("é", " ", "'"), "", html_entity_decode($string));`

Comment: May be this will work array("&egrave;", " ", "'").

Comment: on php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php they are saying: Please note that all the discussion about mb_str_replace in the comments is pretty pointless. str_replace works just fine with multibyte strings. Also, it is not in the Table of Contents

Comment: _Also see_ The usual problem is that the string is evaluated as binary string, meaning PHP is not aware of encodings at all. Problems arise if you are getting a value "from outside" somewhere (database, POST request) and the encoding of the needle and the haystack is not the same. That typically means the source code is not saved in the same encoding as you are receiving "from outside". Therefore the binary representations don't match and nothing happens.

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually when I execute my code the string that is displayed is: "Qualitdel'air", so it works just fine for the "é" and the space.

Comment: Just in case its relevant, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I run your code and geta result of `Qualitdelair` but my PHP source file is encoded as `U8-Unix`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works, thank you

Comment: @RiggsFolly the version of php is 5.6.30

Comment: I get that same answer with 5.6.30 i.e. `Qualitdelair` but source code as I said is encoded as UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some special chars encoded as entities.

Revert them into literal chars with [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and then run the `str_replace`:

```
$newString = str_replace(array("é", " ", "'"), "", html_entity_decode($string));
```